# Reading timecode track data using the C# version of Quicktime

Tags: c#, quicktime

I'm using the .Net activeX component of Quicktime.
I would like to read the timecode track data contained in a QTMovie track.
I can already select my timecode track like this :

```
// Valid Quicktime movie
QTMovie movie;
QTUtils qtu = new QTUtils();

for (int i = 1; i <= movie.Tracks.Count; i++)
{
    if (movie.Tracks[i].Type == qtu.StringToFourCharCode("tmcd"))
    {
        QTTrack tcTrack = movie.Tracks[i];
        //
        // Timecode data reading ?
        //
}
```

Is there a way to extract the timecode data?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am trying to research this exact problem.  I am also looking at the quicktime SDK as a possible solution.  Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I know that this is possible with the Quicktime SDK, I did in another program I wrote but I don't have the source code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[I asked a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123324/is-there-any-way-of-reading-a-timecode-track-of-a-quicktime-movie-with-applescrip) regarding applescript and timecode. The workaround was to use another app, an open source, command line app called timecodereader available [here](http://www.creative-workflow-hacks.com/2006/08/29/reading-quicktime-timecode-in-after-effects-redux-a-solution/). I'm not sure if it's cross platform, but you might be able to glean something from the sourc code.

HTH