# Is there any way of reading a timecode track of a Quicktime movie with applescript

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I want to extract the timecode from a quicktime movie in Applescript.

By using this script

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set themovie to open thefile
    set thetracks to tracks of document 1
    repeat with thetrack in thetracks
        if the kind of thetrack is "Timecode" then
            get the properties of thetrack
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

I can get the timecode track, the properties of the track are:

> {is audio variable rate:true, is video
>   gray scale:false, audio sample size:0,
>   class:track, audio sample rate:0.0,
>   sound balance:0, preload:false,
>   streaming bit rate:-1.0,
>   duration:960300, language:"English",
>   audio channel count:0, layer:0,
>   contents:missing value, bass gain:0,
>   start time:0, data format:"Timecode",
>   treble gain:0, audio
>   characteristic:false, sound volume:0,
>   mask:missing value, video depth:0,
>   position:{0, 0}, id:4, high
>   quality:false, deinterlace
>   fields:false, href:"", natural
>   dimensions:{0, 0}, single field:false,
>   kind:"Timecode", index:4, data
>   size:38412, visual
>   characteristic:false, data rate:100,
>   never purge:false, transparency:49,
>   chapterlist:{}, name:"Timecode Track",
>   alternate:{}, operation color:{32768,
>   32768, 32768}, enabled:true,
>   type:"tmcd", streaming quality:-1.0,
>   transfer mode:transfer mode unknown,
>   dimensions:{0, 0}, current
>   matrix:{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0,
>   0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}}}

none of which seems to have anything to do with the timecode. Note that the contents property is "missing value"

If I try to get the current time of the movie it returns 0, even if the timecode doesn't start at 0.

I'm thinking by what I've found on the net so far that this is impossible. Please prove me wrong

TIA
-stib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. There is an open source, command line app called timecodereader available [here](http://www.creative-workflow-hacks.com/2006/08/29/reading-quicktime-timecode-in-after-effects-redux-a-solution/)

Now it requires a little hacking, on line 152 of timecodereader.m you need to change the output from stderr to stdout, so that applescript can read the result. Like so:

```
fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", [timecodeString fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

to

```
fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", [timecodeString fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

once you've built it and put the result in your executable path you can just use

```
set theStartTC to do shell script "timecodereader /Posix/Path/To/My/Movie.mov"
```

it returns a string with the first frame of timecode.

Comment: You could probably just redirect stderr. Put ` 2>&1` at the end of the shell command string to redirect stderr to go wherever stdout is going.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of the track instead of kind:

```
on open myfiles
 repeat with thefile in myfiles

  tell application "QuickTime Player"
   set themovie to open thefile
   set thetracks to tracks of document 1
   repeat with thetrack in thetracks
    if the name of thetrack is "Closed Caption Track" then
     set thetrack's enabled to false

    end if
   end repeat
  end tell
 end repeat
end open
```

Comment: I can get the track ok, using the kind, or the name, it's just that I couldn't access the timecode within that track.